# How to select all option for multiple dropdowns and perform query in php and mysql? easier method?

Tags: php, sql, html-select

I am new to php and sql so please bear with me. I did try and search but did not find quite wat i am looking for. Hope u can help me out. so here goes!

I have a certain number of drop down menus with values. I like to include a select all option which will select all the options and does an sql query for all values.
I have wriiten a sample code using if conditions to perform the query but the number of if cond increase exponentially based on the number of drop down menus. 2^n im guessing.
I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this. please find the code below.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT distinct `Num. of Parts` from `$verb`");
echo "<select name='filter1'>";
echo "<option value='1'> Select all </option>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$filter1 = $row['Num. of Parts'];
echo "<option value='$filter1'> $filter1 </option>";
}
echo "</select>";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT distinct `Type of positioning` from `$verb`");
echo "<select name='filter2'>";
echo "<option value='1'> Select all </option>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$filter2 = $row['Type of positioning'];
echo "<option value='$filter2'> $filter2 </option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submitC\" value=\"SUBMIT\">";
```

the submitC value is passed here:

```
if($filter1==1 && $filter2!=1)
{$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from `$verb` where `Num. of Parts` like '%' and `Type of positioning`='$filter2' and `Distance range`='$dist'");
}
elseif($filter1!=1 && $filter2==1)
{$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from `$verb` where `Num. of Parts`='$filter1' and `Type of positioning` like '%' and `Distance range`='$dist'");
}
elseif($filter1==1 && $filter2==1)
{$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from `$verb` where `Num. of Parts` like '%' and `Type of positioning` like '%' and `Distance range`='$dist'");
}
else
{
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from `$verb` where `Num. of Parts`='$filter1' and `Type of positioning`='$filter2' and `Distance range`='$dist'");
}
```

Thanks in advance guys!
ps EXCLUDE $dist

Answer (score 1):

you can select multiple option by `name='filter1[]'`

and you can store these by `$filter1=   serialize($_POST['filter1']) ;`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if($filter1==1) {  if(&& $filter2!=1){
$sql = "SELECT * from `$verb` where `Num. of Parts` like '%' and `Type of positioning`='$filter2' and `Distance range`='$dist'"; }
elseif($filter2==1){$sql = "SELECT * from `$verb` where `Num. of Parts` like '%' and `Type of positioning` like '%' and `Distance range`='$dist'";  }  }

elseif($filter1!=1 && $filter2==1) { 
$sql = "SELECT * from `$verb` where `Num. of Parts`='$filter1' and `Type of positioning` like '%' and `Distance range`='$dist'";  }

else{
$sql = "SELECT * from `$verb` where `Num. of Parts`='$filter1' and `Type of positioning`='$filter2' and `Distance range`='$dist'";  }

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right you are searching something like this :

```
<?php

$mapping = array ( 'column1' => 'Num_of_Parts' , 
      'column2' => 'Type_of_positioning'
);  
    $sql = "select * from table ";
    $connector = " AND ";
    if ( isset($_POST['filters']) ) {
        $sql = $sql . "where ";
        foreach ($_POST['filters'] as $key=>$val) {
            $sql .= $mapping[$key] ." like '%"  . $val. "%'" . $connector ; 
        }

    }//end of if
    $sql.= " Distance range = 'value'";
    var_dump($sql);


?>


<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<select name = "filters[column1]">
  <option value="">Select All</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name = "filters[column2]">
  <option value="">Select All</option>
  <option value="saab">Car</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Bus</option>
  <option value="audi">Cycle</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

### Note

1. Always sanitize user inputs by using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)  or something similar like this but do not use mysql family functions as they are encouraged not to use in [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).
2. ***Do not use column names*** as the name of the elements for security purpose. You can see in the code how to remap column names by using just a simple trick.

Happy coding :)